# CakePHP 3 REST API ajax login solution

Tags: rest, authentication, cakephp-3.x

Is there any solutions? I am trying to make REST API in CakePHP 3. 
in middleware

```
->add(new CsrfProtectionMiddleware([
                'httpOnly' => true
            ]))
            ->add(function($request, $response, $next) {
                return $next($request, $response)
                        ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
                        ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','*')
                        ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true)
                        ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*')
                        ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Type', 'application/json');

            });
```

get request is ok but can't send post request

Comment: https://github.com/ozee31/cakephp-cors might help you with this functionality.

Comment: yes,  i tried no diffrence

Comment: You'll probably need to add more details then, with specifics of your POST, request and response headers, what you're expecting to see vs what you actually see, that sort of thing. Because this is working for other people, meaning that the problem must be elsewhere.